# AspNetCompiler including files that are not in my project

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, aspnet-compiler

I'm using msbuild to automatically build and package a website ready for deployment. When I compile and then Publish my project through Visual Studio 2008 everything works fine.

However when I use msbuild I'm getting errors because AspNetCompiler is trying to compile aspx and ascx files that are not included in my .csproj, but still exist in version control.

I know I can just remove them from version control, but can anyone tell me why these files are being compiled?

Here is my msbuild task.

```
    <AspNetCompiler                
     TargetPath="$(PackageDir)\Web"
     VirtualPath="/"
     PhysicalPath="$(buildDirectory)\Web"
     Force="true"
     />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *AspNetCompiler* task, which wraps _aspnet_compiler.exe_, compiles all "compilable" files in the application, rather than compiling only those files in the *.csproj*.

The giveaway is that none of the command-line parameters for the executable take a *.csproj* as input, only paths. (I suppose one could argue that it would look for a *.csproj* in the directory, but that is unlikely as it would introduce its own set of issues, such as what to do if someone had put two project files in one directory.)

Comment: Good comments. Got some project cleanup to do!